# How to iterate through hash and compare with another?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in the following code i have myestate which can contain 0 1 or more elements, what if i want to find the User where i can compare each element in the myestate with user? how can I do that because the current code gives no method error which is correct, but do iterate through each of the myestate and compare id?

```
myestate = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company)
@managements = User.where(:id => myestate.user_id)
```

Comment: I suggest to be familiar with Rails basic guide and go through some tuts before coding directly. There are several basic errors.

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a step back and rereading the question, then trying to format it and reword it so it's more readable and understandable. As is, it's like it was written after way too much coffee. You want it to clearly state your question so potential answerers immediately grok your meaning and intent.